# How to keep chatbar always open in Twilio Flex Web Chat

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using Twilio UI 1.8.2 and Twilio Webchat UI 1.2.0, How can I keep expanded the chat window of Twilio Customer Chat Panel if the page is refreshed or open the same page (session) in new tab/page in the browser.

By default, if I refresh the page it is started from minimized.

I am using Twilio's built-in flex (reactjs version) and expanding as my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What I would do is hook into the [actions framework of the webchat UI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-webchat-actions), listening for the `ToggleChatVisibility` action and save the open state of the chat into `localStorage`. Then when the page loads, load the state from `localStorage` and invoke the `ToggleChatVisibility` action if the chat should be open.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thank you very much @philnash . It's working. Though I did not use `isEntryPointExpanded`, I just invoke action `ToggleChatVisibility` when the visibility is already `true`.

Comment: Fantastic! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so that others can see it helped too?

Comment: Hi @philnash, sure, I marked the answer with an upvote.

Comment: If you hit the check mark, it marks the answer as accepted rather than just voting it up :)

Comment: Thank you! Hope the rest of your app goes well.